Attempting to use color matrices to dynamically re-color high-res images at runtime in C#
I am trying to create a class that can re-color high-res images in realtime with as little lag as possible.  I settled on using color matrices because the recommended method of pixel-wise color replacement using lookup tables would be restrictive and computationally prohibitive.  However, as far as I can tell, no one has actually done this before (which I find extremely hard to believe).  I have pieced together my best guess using a variety of resources, the most useful of which have been:
https://graficaobscura.com/matrix/index.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/hue-rotate?redirectedfrom=MSDN
Rotate Hue in C#
The problem is that the code I have come up with does not work quite right, and unfortunately I can't tell just by looking at a color what has gone wrong, making debugging nearly impossible.
Here's what I currently have for my recolor class:
public class Recolorer
{    
    const float LumR = 0.2126f;
    const float LumG = 0.7152f;
    const float LumB = 0.0722f;
    
    public bool UseSat = true;
    public bool UseLum = false;
    public bool UseBri = true;
    
    public Bitmap Recolor(Bitmap bm, Color BaseColor, Color NewColor)
    {
        float r = 1;
        float d = 0;
        d = BrightnessDelta(BaseColor, NewColor);
        
        float[][] H = HueMatrix(NewColor, BaseColor.GetHue());
        float[][] S = SaturationMatrix(NewColor);
        float[][] L = LuminosityMatrix();
        float[][] B = LightnessMatrix(r, d);
        float[][] T = H;
        if (UseSat)
            T = Multiply(S, T);
        if (UseLum)
            T = Multiply(L, T);
        if (UseBri)
            T = Multiply(B, T);
        
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(T);
        ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
        ia.SetColorMatrix(cm);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height);
        Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temp);
        g.DrawImage(bm, rect, 0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
        return temp;
    }
    
    public float[][] LuminosityMatrix(float B = 1f)
    {
        return new float[][] {
            new float[] {LumR * B, LumR * B, LumR * B, 0, 0},
            new float[] {LumG * B, LumG * B, LumG * B, 0, 0},
            new float[] {LumB * B, LumB * B, LumB * B, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        };
    }
    
    public float[][] SaturationMatrix(Color c)
    {
        float s = c.GetSaturation();
        float sr = (1f - s) * LumR;
        float sg = (1f - s) * LumG;
        float sb = (1f - s) * LumB;
        
        return new float[][] {
            new float[] {sr+s, sr, sr, 0, 0},
            new float[] {sg, sg+s, sg, 0, 0},
            new float[] {sb, sb, sb+s, 0, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
        };
    }
    
    public float[][] HueMatrix(Color c, float x = 0)
    {
        float angle = c.GetHue() - x;
        angle /= 180f;
        float cos = (float)Math.Cos(angle * Math.PI);
        float sin = (float)Math.Sin(angle * Math.PI);
        
        float A00 = LumR + (1 - LumR) * cos - LumR * sin;
        float A01 = LumR - LumR * cos + 0.413f * sin;
        float A02 = LumR - LumR * cos - (1 - LumR) * sin;
        
        float A10 = LumG - LumG * cos - LumG * sin;
        float A11 = LumG + (1 - LumG) * cos + 0.140f * sin;
        float A12 = LumG - LumG * cos + LumG * sin;
        
        float A20 = LumB - LumB * cos + (1 - LumB) * sin;
        float A21 = LumB - LumB * cos - 0.283f * sin;
        float A22 = LumB + (1 - LumB) * cos + LumB * sin;
        
        return new float[][] {
            new float[] { A00, A01, A02,  0,  0 },
            new float[] { A10, A11, A12,  0,  0 },
            new float[] { A20, A21, A22,  0,  0 },
            new float[] {   0,   0,   0,  1,  0 },
            new float[] {   0,   0,   0,  0,  1 }
        };
    }
    
    public float GetBrightness(Color c)
    {
        return (((float)c.R * LumR / 255f) + ((float)c.G * LumG / 255f) + ((float)c.B * LumB / 255f));
    }
    
    public float BrightnessRatio(Color From, Color To)
    {
        return (GetBrightness(To) / GetBrightness(From));
    }
    
    public float BrightnessDelta(Color From, Color To)
    {
        return ((GetBrightness(To) - GetBrightness(From)) / 2f);
    }
    
    public float[][] LightnessMatrix(float f = 1, float l = 0)
    {
        return new float[][] {
            new float[] { f, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, f, 0, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, f, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            new float[] { l, l, l, 0, 1 }
        };
    }
            
    public float[][] Multiply(float[][] A, float[][] B)
    {
        const int size = 5;
        float temp = 0;
        
        float[][] C = new float[size][];
        for (int sigh = 0; sigh<size; sigh++)
            C[sigh] = new float[size];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                temp = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
                {
                    temp += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                }
                C[i][j] = temp;
            }
        }
        return C;
    }
}

As you can probably tell, I have trouble keeping brightness/lightness/luminosity/luminance straight, so I struggle to figure out which to use and how to apply it, but nothing I try seems to get the right brightness.  As the two examples below show, the recolored images invariably end up washed out and with compressed brightness.  The hue seems to work correctly, as trying to change the image to red makes it red(ish) and changing it to green makes it green, and so on for every color I've tried.
(The skirt's original color is blue)




I do not think it is possible to rotate the hue using just color matrices. The matrices represents a linear transform. RGB -> HSL is not a linear transform, nor is there any linear RGB->RGB transform that corresponds to an arbitrary hue rotation while preserving luminance and saturation.
The way I would approach the problem would be to use lockbits to get direct access to the pixeldata. That avoid the need for expensive operations like GetPixel or creating graphics objects.
You can then implement your conversion code for each pixel. You can try optimize the code as much as possible. SIMD and/or multithreading might help. Do not underestimate the the speed of modern CPUs running well optimized code.
I would also not dismiss a lookup table out of hand, for 24 bit RGB that should be about 50Mb, so most of it should fit into the last level cache. Memory access is 'slow', but so are branches, so I'm not sure what option would be faster.
You could also look into using a shader to run the conversion on the GPU, this will likely be fastest by far if you have a decent GPU.

Firstly, I would like to say thank you for taking the time to respond, I appreciate it.  As for the impossibility of hue rotation using a color matrix, I have seen that answer posted in several places, but I don't believe it's accurate.  The transformation isn't linear, it is circular, which is why you need the sine and cosine of hue rotation angle.  I believe the confusion comes from the fact that it's impossible to do an absolute hue rotation, ie. "any color to blue".  You need a starting point, ie. "red to blue" so that you know the hue rotation angle to use

@goodri63 A rotation transform is still a linear transform. I think you can do 120 degree hue rotations with a simple linear transform, but for an arbitrary angle it is just not sufficient. Not while keeping L & S constant.

I can't seem to add a picture to a comment, so I edited my post to add the picture showing the hue rotation seemingly working for every 30 degrees from 0 to 330.  I found the same hue rotation matrix that I'm using right now on multiple different sites.  I find it hard to believe that they are all wrong, and even moreso when the results seem to be what I would expect to see if it was working.  Again, I am no color master, so I can't be sure the results are exactly right, but they seem good to me.

@goodri63 That makes no sense to me. 30 degrees hue rotation would mean you map red->orange, orange->yellow, and yellow -> greenyellow. A linear transform means any straight line remains straight after the transformation. red-orange-yellow is a straight line in RGB space. But orange-yellow-greenyellow is not a straight line. So such a transform would not be linear, and cannot be represented with a color matrix. I would recommend writing some unit tests to transform individual colors if you do not believe me.
